# Despite changing the name of the package, app name doesn't change

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a project, call it 'X', I wanted to change it's name to 'Y', and I ended up making a new project called 'Y' and copying all of 'X' files into 'Y'. Despite the project being called 'Y', when I install the app on my phone it's name shows 'X'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change only one thing. Just go to string.xml file and change app_name "X" to "Y".

Comment: That was it. Silly of me to overlook that. Thank you!